# How to create my own module in October CMS?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I'm a newbie in OctoberCMS. My team is going to use OctoberCMS to create a dynamic website. I was tasked to create a simple module similar to eventbrite, like managing events and tickets. What is the best approach in developing such module?

PS.

All I see is to create the module by plugin but currently looking to make it in a normal way, laravel way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to create a plugin. Very easy to do you can have what you want in no more than an hour really.

Download the builder plugin to create a plugin, set up the database, create the models. If I am making a plugin that doesn't need a backend controller I end here and work with the components. If I need to work with it in the backend then I continue to create the fields, lists, backend menu, and controller.

Components are the bread and butter to OctoberCMS Plugins and you will mostly be working them. Go over the [docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration) and use what OctoberCMS provides instead of reinventing the wheel.